# Low Fps on face tracking C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I have written this code to track a person's face but however, I'm getting very low fps. When I only do video my fps is a lot higher.

I have tried changing the resolution but that did not work.

```
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/objdetect.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int main(int argv, char** argc)
{

    CascadeClassifier faceCascade;
    faceCascade.load("C:\\Users\\farha\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\OpenCV4\\OpenCv\\install\\etc\\haarcascades\\haarcascade_frontalface_alt_tree.xml");

    Mat frame;
    Mat frameGray;
    VideoCapture cap(0);

    while (1)
    {
        cap >> frame;
        cvtColor(frame, frameGray, COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
        vector<Rect> faces;
        faceCascade.detectMultiScale(frame, faces);
        for (int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++)
        {
            //int x1 = faces[i].x;
            //int y1 = faces[i].y;
            Point pt1(faces[i].x, faces[i].y);
            Point pt2(faces[i].x + faces[i].width, faces[i].height + faces[i].y);//, (faces[i].y, faces[i].width)
            rectangle(frame, pt1, pt2, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2, 8, 0);

        }
        waitKey(1);
        imshow("Window", frame);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you calculate fps of your camera or webcam without facedetection?

Comment: What compilation flags did you use?